# Cocoapods SwiftWebSocket in Xcode project - library is not found

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift4

I'm experimenting with [SwiftWebSocket](https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket) in Swift using Xcode 10.1.

I've added the pod via this podfile:

```
platform :osx, '10.14'
target 'ViewWebSocketLearning' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'SwiftWebSocket', '~> 2.7'
end
```

and I've loaded the pod as follows:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using SwiftWebSocket (2.7.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

which produces a workspace with the SwiftWebSocket project included in it. I compiled the projects and you can see that it is correctly compiling both my empty project and the SwiftWebSocket project properly. Everything is looking good so far.

However as soon as I try to include a reference to the SwiftWebSocket project in my project's unit tests, Xcode chokes. Here's a snip of my code:

```
import SwiftWebSocket
...
let ws = WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org")
```

I get "No such module 'SwiftWebSocket'". If I take out the import, I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'WebSocket'". So something isn't linking properly by the looks of it.

I've tried adding the compiled framework from the SwiftWebSocket project to mine in the project organizer on the left, no change. I've added it to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries in the target settings, again no change.

What am I missing?

I'm a relative novice to Xcode so apologies but I really would like to get past this point so your help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You might want to add to your podfile: `target 'ViewWebSocketLearningTest' do ... end` and add also the pod to your testing target.

Comment: That's a great idea - and it does appear to work!

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the solution I was shooting for, but I solved this by building a class in my project which contains the logic to control the SwiftWebSocket, then called that class from inside the unit tests.

Architecturally this is probably cleaner but I remain unclear on why I couldn't access the SwitfWebSocket directly from the unit tests.